# Select unique items

Tags: powershell, unique

I have a piece of code

```
Get-XASession -AccountDisplayName DOM\UserA -ComputerName XenA1  | FT ClientAddress,SessionId,SessionName,ServerName,AccountName
```

that outputs

> ClientAddress SessionId   SessionName      ServerName AccountName
>   ------------- ---------   -----------      ---------- -----------
>   192.168.2.139 4       ICA-TCP#1          ServerA       UserA
>   192.168.2.88  13  ICA-TCP#11       ServerB       UserA
>   192.168.2.88  13  ICA-TCP#11         ServerB       UserA
>   192.168.2.139 17  ICA-TCP#15         ServerA       UserA

How can I get a list of unique ClientAddress from this list/output? That is I would like to get a list of all the ClientAddress'

Answer (score 0):

Get-XASession -AccountDisplayName DOM\UserA -ComputerName XenA1 | Select-Object ClientAddress -Unique